# NHibernate eager loaded tree hits the database when walked by Automapper

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading, automapper, hierarchy, eager-loading

I ran into a strange NHibernate and Automapper problem. I am not sure which one is to blame but I am struggling for a whole day now and I can't seem to find out why.

Here is my Nhibernate mapping files:

Navigation.hbm.xml

```
<id name="ID" column="NavigationID">
  <generator class="identity"></generator>
</id>

<property name="IsDefault"/>
<property name="RoleType" column="RoleTypeID" />

<bag  name="Items" cascade="save-update" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="join">
  <key column="NavigationID"/>
  <one-to-many class="NavigationItem"/>
</bag>
```

NavigationItem.hbm.xml

```
 <class name="NavigationItem" table="NavigationItem">

<id name="ID" column="NavigationItemID">
  <generator class="identity"></generator>
</id>

<property name="ShowInMenu"/>
<property name="Order" column="[Order]" />

<many-to-one name="Page" column="PageID" lazy="false" fetch="join" />
<many-to-one name="Navigation" column="NavigationID" />
<many-to-one name="Parent" column="ParentNavigationItemID" />

<bag  name="Items" cascade="save-update" inverse="true">
  <key column="ParentNavigationItemID"/>
  <one-to-many class="NavigationItem"/>
</bag>
```

This is how I fill up a Navigation object:

```
ISession session = SessionProvider.Instance.CurrentSession;

            using (transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var navigation = session.QueryOver<Navigation>()
                    .Where(x => x.IsDefault && x.RoleType == null)
                    .TransformUsing(new NHibernate.Transform.RootEntityResultTransformer())
                    .SingleOrDefault();

                transaction.Commit();
                return navigation;
            }
```

Since the Items bag on the Navigation object is set to lazy="false", I get only one query to the database to get the Navigation object and a left join to get all the Navigation items as well.

All is perfect until now.

I did a test to iterate through all the items and the sub-items recursive and no more hits to the database.

Then, I have an UI model that I map with Automapper.

Here are the UI models:

```
public class NavigationModel
{
    public List<NavigationItemModel> Items { get; set; }

    public NavigationModel()
    {
        Items = new List<NavigationItemModel>();
    }
}

public class NavigationItemModel
{
    public string PageName { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }

    public NavigationItemModel Parent { get; set; }
    public List<NavigationItemModel> Items { get; set; }
}
```

And the automapper mappings:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper
            .CreateMap<NavigationItem, NavigationItemModel>()
 // IF I REMOVE THE NEXT LINE, IT HITS THE DATABASE FOR EACH SUB-ITEM of the NavigationItem.Items
            .ForMember(m => m.Items, o => o.Ignore()); 

        AutoMapper.Mapper
            .CreateMap<Navigation, NavigationModel>();
```

Ok, now the behavior is like this:

- If I ignore the NavigationItem.Items member in the mapping, all goes well, but only the Navigation and it's items are mapped. No sub-items collection of the navigation's Items are mapped. BUT the database is not hit anymore. But I want the other items mapped as well...
- If I remove the line under the comment, the database is hit for each of the Navigation.Items, querying for it's sub-items (where ParentID = Item.ID).

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Sorry for the wall of text, but I thought better to describe it in more detail, I spent the whole day on this one and I tried all kind of queries with Future and JoinQueryOver, etc. The problem does not seem to be with NHibernate since that loads fine and I can iterate without any more calls to the database.

---

I forgot to include the SQL that is being generated:

First there is this query:

```
SELECT this_.NavigationID             as Navigati1_7_2_,
   this_.IsDefault                as IsDefault7_2_,
   this_.RoleTypeID               as RoleTypeID7_2_,
   items2_.NavigationID           as Navigati5_4_,
   items2_.NavigationItemID       as Navigati1_4_,
   items2_.NavigationItemID       as Navigati1_4_0_,
   items2_.ShowInMenu             as ShowInMenu4_0_,
   items2_.[Order]                as column3_4_0_,
   items2_.PageID                 as PageID4_0_,
   items2_.NavigationID           as Navigati5_4_0_,
   items2_.ParentNavigationItemID as ParentNa6_4_0_,
   page3_.PageID                  as PageID8_1_,
   page3_.Name                    as Name8_1_,
   page3_.Title                   as Title8_1_,
   page3_.Description             as Descript4_8_1_,
   page3_.URL                     as URL8_1_
FROM   Navigation this_
   left outer join NavigationItem items2_
     on this_.NavigationID = items2_.NavigationID
   left outer join Page page3_
     on items2_.PageID = page3_.PageID
WHERE  (this_.IsDefault = 1 /* @p0 */
    and this_.RoleTypeID is null)
```

Then, when Automapper comes into play, a list of these queries are being generated, only the p0 parameter differs (from 1 to 12 ... the number of items without parents )

```
SELECT items0_.ParentNavigationItemID as ParentNa6_2_,
   items0_.NavigationItemID       as Navigati1_2_,
   items0_.NavigationItemID       as Navigati1_4_1_,
   items0_.ShowInMenu             as ShowInMenu4_1_,
   items0_.[Order]                as column3_4_1_,
   items0_.PageID                 as PageID4_1_,
   items0_.NavigationID           as Navigati5_4_1_,
   items0_.ParentNavigationItemID as ParentNa6_4_1_,
   page1_.PageID                  as PageID8_0_,
   page1_.Name                    as Name8_0_,
   page1_.Title                   as Title8_0_,
   page1_.Description             as Descript4_8_0_,
   page1_.URL                     as URL8_0_
FROM   NavigationItem items0_
   left outer join Page page1_
     on items0_.PageID = page1_.PageID
WHERE  items0_.ParentNavigationItemID = 1 /* @p0 */
```

This is taken from the NHProf application, hope it helps.

Thank you,
Cosmin

Comment: Hi Cosmin, can you post the SQL that's executed?

Comment: Hello James, I have edited the question with the SQL generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think AutoMapper is mapping your classes recursively. If this is the case, than you can specifiy the max depth for your mappings using

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>().MaxDepth(2); // or 1, or 3, or whatever
```

Comment: Yes, it does, but I want to have this. The problem is that I want AutoMapper to map them recursively but not hit the database. The information is all there, loaded by NHIbernate.

My question is, why does NHibernate thinks he needs to hit the database when AutoMapper goes through the object hierarchy?

Comment: So a call to navigation.Items[0].Items[0] doesn't trigger the database query?

Comment: Not sure, but i don't think every NavigationItem.Items collection is mapped from your query. Maybe specifying batch-size on your bag may improve performance, by batching requests. I am currently working with an NHibernate project with a lot of hierarchical relationships in my entities and I found it very hard to load an entire aggregate root with all collections with one query without using a separate many-to-many join table like in this blog post http://ayende.com/blog/3107/dealing-with-hierarchical-structures-in-databases

Comment: No, but I just did another test. If i iterate through items and sub-items recursive, like I did before, no call to the database.

However, if in this call I access a property and do something with it, like `var a = item.ID *3`, a call to the database is made.

My conclusion is then that AutoMapper is not the issue, but why does NHibernate goes to the database when I eager loaded the collections of items and sub-items? Is something wrong with the way I specify in the mapping that it should be `lazy=false` and `fetch="join"`?

Because I see the query is getting all the data in one step...

Comment: I assume it cannot load all NavigationItem.Items collections

Comment: Ok, so bottom line is that `Navigation.Items` is loading. From your article, I have found another article that I have also used some time ago. I will use a left / right index to store the items, and only one level of hierarchy (the items will not have sub-items).

So, I will load ALL the items in the navigation, with their left/right indexes and rebuild the tree on the client.

The article is this one: (http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/)

Thank you for your help, it was really useful!

Comment: It is all about nHibernate lazy load. Automapper tries to map all properties (references) so via reflection it hits some of the properties on object that have proxies. After that action nHibernate thinks that you need that object or collections and it lazily loads data.

Comment: Yes it is, but the problem was that his model was hierarchical, so AutoMapper was recursively loading the entire graph hitting properties that were not loaded. Even though he was querying for all entities, it doesn't mean that all the relationships between them were set.